# Why doesn't modal have access to external controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Say I have in my main html:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="session as vmSession">
...
<!-- Modal will get created here -->
</body>
```

And in my modal I have a link:

```
<a ui-sref="siteManagement({ site: vmSession.user.site._id })" ng-click="$dismiss()">Example</a>
```

The button doesn't have the correct link, instead it points to the root `siteManagement` page, not the specific one for the logged in user.
I've noticed that the modal window is created with an `ng-isolate-scope` class, is that what's stopping this from working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `$modal.open()` you can specify which `$scope` object the modal controller's scope will be inherited from like this:

```
$modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'modal.html',
  controller: 'modal',
  scope: $scope
});
```

If the `scope:` is missing, it will be defaulted to `$rootScope`, which is the parent of the scope of your session controller, that why it can't be access the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the `resolve` option as suggested in one of the answers there is a `scope` option to the `open` method. Using the `scope` option you can pass any scope you want you modal's scope to be based on. So what you could do is to pass controller's scope as the `scope` attribute and have modal "seeing" all the variables that your controller is seeing.

Please note that `$modal` will create a child scope of the scope you provided (or $rootScope if none is provided) as not to pollute the provided scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any variable to your modal controller:

```
  $scope.openModal = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: '/templates/modal/yourModal.html',
      controller: YourModalCtrl,
      resolve: {
        values: function () {
          return {
            aValue: '123',
            anotherValue: {a: 'A', b: 'B'}
          };
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
        // ok result
    }, function (result) {
       // cancel result
    });
  };


var StepModalCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, values) {
   var aValue = values.aValue;
   var anotherValue = values.anotherValue;

   $scope.doSomething = function () {
      console.log(aValue);
   };

   $scope.save = function () {          
       $modalInstance.close($scope.YourResult);
   };

   $scope.close = function () {
      $modalInstance.dismiss($scope.YourResult);
   };
};
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but the whole point of the session controller being attached to the root <body> tag is so that I have access to the vmSession controller throughout my application, saving me from duplicating code in all my controllers. Creating a controller for a modal just for the sake of passing it a value that *should* already be available seems like a lot of unnecessary work.